# Reset special price on a store via soap api

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, soap

I am really struggling to remove a special price and setting the flag `Use default value` on a store level via soap api. I tried both `catalog_product.setSpecialPrice` and `catalog_product.update` (see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalogProduct.html) but it does not work.

In the meantime I have a workaround with setting the special price with a string of zero length ("") to null. Not very satisfying though but at least it works more than half way I would like to. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$result = $client->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product.setSpecialPrice', array('product' => 'productId Or SKU', 'specialPrice' => '', 'fromDate' => '', 'toDate' => ''));
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either. It comes back with the success result `["update"=>true, "special"=>1]` but it actually has not switched on the `Use default value`.

Comment: Just correcting my comment above: The success result is purely `1`. I just mixed up the result with an accumulated result array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for people arriving here by google/search: I can confirm that setting the special_price to an empty string instead of null will reset the `Use default value` option.

Using `null` will not remove a special price.